# Database advice for counting wins/losses between players

Tags: database, redundancy

What is the best way to keep track of the scores between all the players from a database ? How many times a player won/lost against another.

I thought about a `duel` table where I would have 3 colums: `duel_id`, `winner_id` and `loser_id` but I believe there is a better way to do this, avoiding redundancies.

**Edit:** I'm very sorry for not being clear enough. The players are in fact picked randomly from a `user` table. I need to know who won/lost against whom. And the reason why I don't really like my solution is because when doing statistics, the whole `duel` table would have to be scanned in order to return the amount of wins/losses between two players.

Comment: I do not see how an association array (this is what your duel table is essentially) can be redundant. But I would say the "best" is not a universal term, it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table with its own `id`, two foreign keys - `player1_id`, `player2_id`, and two columns for wins `wins_player1`, `wins_player2`.

```
--------------------------------
| id | p1_id | p2_id | w1 | w2 |
--------------------------------
| 1  |   1   |   2   |  2 |  0 |
--------------------------------
| 2  |   1   |   3   |  1 |  1 |
--------------------------------
| ...|       |       |    |    |
--------------------------------
```

This way, when two players play a game you don't insert a new tuple to the table, you just update their scores.

For an example, if players 1 and 2 played, and the player 1 won you would do:

```
UPDATE scores WHERE p1_id = 1 AND p2_id = 2 SET w1 = w1 + 1;
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting, would you also be able to use the `ON DUPLICATE` with this method would be a straight query to do it all ?

Comment: I believe you would be able to do it. Not sure if `ON DUPLICATE` works on foreign keys, though

Comment: I actually considered this solution as well. This would require checking after each game if the tuple exists for both players and if the winner's id is `p1_id` or `p2_id`. I'm going to think about it!

Comment: Well, to avoid checking, you could consider a rule of a thumb: let p1_id always hold the smaller player id.

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t mind not knowing who dueled with whom, you can put a total_wins column in your user data table, and increment it for each user after each match.

It has the advantage of not taking too much space.

But if you have a pretty big applications your data base could lock up with so many querys and writes